# Mysql giving error sometimes as Incorrect DateTime value

Tags: mysql, datetime, go, timestamp

I am running a mysql query using golang:

query: `UPDATE RESTORE_TIMESTAMP SET last_restored_at=? where id=?`, updatedTime, 1

Here updatedTime is in strfmt.DateTime format in go.
This query runs fine for some time but after that it starts failing with below error.
Sometimes after mysql retries it passes but most of the times it is failing.
I'm not getting any clue why is this happening.

**Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '2020-10-19T16:25:08.958Z' for column `db`.`RESTORE_TIMESTAMP`.`last_restored_at` at row 1"**

table details:
MariaDB [db]> show columns from RESTORE_TIMESTAMP;

```
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field            | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| id               | enum('1') | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| last_restored_at | timestamp | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |       |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

I have only one row in my table as above and I need to update that every time.

Please point me somewhere how can I resolve this query failure.

Comment: What do you mean by strfmt.DateTime? Do not format the time yourself. Use a [time.Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) value as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You should to apply [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) conversion for convert your date into DB format

```
UPDATE RESTORE_TIMESTAMP 
SET last_restored_at=STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
WHERE id=?;
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=bd0b3538776885402aac01cd54b5500c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: I'll check, but my query is sometimes passing and sometimes failing.